# Как вычислить разницу дней и часов между двумя введенными датами?

Tags: дата, android, время

Есть 4 поля EditText, где пользователь выбирает дату, время начала и дату, время окончания  и поле TextView, куда нужно вывести данные о разнице дней между введенными датами:

```
etDateStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDateStart);
etTimeStart = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTimeStart);
etDateEnd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDateEnd);
etTimeEnd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTimeEnd);

tvInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInfo);
```

Как я могу посчитать эту разницу (нужны только дни и часы) и вывести инфу в TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример:
1) Создаёте два экземпляра календаря.
2) Берёте в мс время.
3) Вычитаете.

```
GregorianCalendar dateStart = new GregorianCalendar(...);
GregorianCalendar dateEnd = new GregorianCalendar(...);

// здесь у нас разница в миллисекундах 
int dif = dateEnd.getTimeInMillis() - dateStart.getTimeInMillis();

const final int HOUR = 3600 * 1000;
const final int DAY = HOUR * 24;

// здесь дни
int days = dif / DAY;
// здесь часы
int hours = (dif - days * DAY) / HOUR;
```

Что-то вроде того, на коленке набросал.

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы считывались данные именно из тех, что введены в EditText? Как можно связать?

Comment: @zloyel, на основе данных из  EditText создавать экземпляры GregorianCalendar. В чём вопрос то? )

Answer (score 1):

getText получаете дату, переводите в секунды. Можно использовать маску ввода, тогда формат даты будет постоянным. По известному формату вырезаете из строки год/месяц/день и переводите в секунды. Тоже самое делаете с второй датой. Отнимаете от второго значения в секундах и переводите обратно.